# Display Image in base64 java HttpServer

Tags: java, image, base64, httpserver

How to display Base64 string in image on Java com.sun.net.httpserver.HttpServer ?

I run this code:

```
static class base implements HttpHandler{

    @Override
    public void handle(HttpExchange he) throws IOException {
        byte[] name = Base64.getEncoder().encode(base64String.getBytes());
        byte[] decodedString = Base64.getDecoder().decode(new String(name).getBytes("UTF-8"));
        String base64String = "BASE64 IMAGE";
        Headers headers = he.getResponseHeaders();
        headers.add("Content-Type", "image/png");

        File file = new File ("1.png");
        //System.out.println(file);
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        InputStream bufferedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedString);
        bufferedInputStream.read(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
        he.sendResponseHeaders(200, decodedString.length);
        final OutputStream os = he.getResponseBody();
        os.write(decodedString);
        os.close();
    }
}
```

But displays a white cube

Comment: What are you using `fileInputStream` for? And why do you read `decodedString` into an input stream back into itself? This doesn't really make sense to me. It should actually be pretty straight forward: You read the image from a file, you base64 encode it, and you send it. Don't forget to add that to your MIME-type.

Comment: Also, what is base64String in the first line of your handler method?

Comment: Plese, write a example code

Comment: Please, give me more information about your code so I can write example code that works

Comment: In Txt files a have a Base64 code, 
I need to convert from base64 to the image and displays image

Comment: So you want to *decode* the image?

Comment: Yes, Base64 >> image >> Show image as png file

Comment: You can use a [Base64.Decoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.html#getDecoder--) and [wrap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Decoder.html#wrap-java.io.InputStream-) it around your [FileInputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/FileInputStream.html)

Comment: Please example code, i'm noob in java